# in c# how to convert an var to a char array. char array[8]

Tags: c#, types, casting

in c# how to convert an varto a char array. char[8] array
I can guarantee this var is not too big.

such as, I have

```
var a = 634711440648369988;
```

and I want `char[8] c` store it.

How to do this conversion correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: I changed my question from "int" to "var". Just let you know. Sorry for inconvenient

Comment: Are you trying to store the 8 bytes that make up a long in a "char" array?  A c# char isn't the same as a c char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast it to a string and use the `ToCharArray` method.

```
char [ ] c = a.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Calling `toString` isn't a cast, though.  It's a method call.

Comment: how to make sure my result array has size of 8? This is very important for me

Comment: @AndersLind if you call `a.ToString().ToCharArray()`, then the array can be pretty any length between 1 to the maximimum number of decimal digits in your number.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BitConverter.GetBytes(long)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ae9768.aspx) or [`BitConverter.GetBytes(ulong)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8z32tce.aspx)

Comment: how to make sure my result array has size of 8? This is very important for me

Comment: @Anders: It depends on which overload you choose.  `Int64` or `UInt64` inputs will produce 8 bytes out.  `Int32` or `UInt32` inputs produce 4 bytes out.  And so on.  So use `ulong a = 634711440648369988;` instead of `var`, to guarantee the exact size.

Answer (score 1):

In C# there is no such thing as `char[8]`. An array of `char` would be `char[]`.

I guess you are coming at this from a C++ viewpoint and actually want an array of bytes, of length 8. In which case the type you need is `byte[]`. Note that you want `byte[]` rather than `char[]` since `char` in C# is a 16 bit data type.

You can obtain what you need by calling `BitConverter.GetBytes()`. When you call this function passing an 8 byte integer, the returned array will be a `byte[]` with length equal to 8, as stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8z32tce.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 123412;

char[] d = a.ToString().ToCharArray();

foreach (char c in d)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I seen the question for different type. Therefore, I'm writing different types.
Firstly, I did split the string to string array,
Secondly, I did convert the string array to var array,
Thirdly, I did convert var array to char array.

```
        string input="q;w;e;r;t;y";
        string[] roleSplit = new string[input.Length];
        roleSplit = input.Split(';');
        var varArray = roleSplit.SelectMany(x => x.ToCharArray());
        char[] charArray = varArray.ToArray();
```